# Acessing variable in object array

Tags: java, class

I am creating a class to sort some data.

```
class data{
            public String text;
            public String day;
            public String direction;
        }

dados vetor[]={};
```

Now I have to have to change a varible and I am doing it this way:

```
vetor[0].text="dumb text";
```

But I am gettting this error:

Attempt to write to field java.lang.String on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did something like :

```
vetor[0] = someInstanceOfData.text; // Store value in array
```

However now `vetor[0]` contains the **value** of the `text` field (i.e. a `String`).
You can not access the `text` field later by doing `vetor[0]`. This refers to the `String` that is stored in that array. So if later the value of the `text` field changes, the vector will still contain the old.

Hence `vetor[0].text="dumb text";` is not assigning the `text` field of some instance of the `data` class, but instead is trying to assign a new value to the String that results from `vetor[0]`.

EDIT : If you want to change the value of the `text` field :

```
Data test = new Data(); // Make an instance of the Data class
test.text = "A String"; // Assign a value
```

If you want to make an array (of strings? or data objects?)

```
Data[] arr = {new Data(), new Data(), new Data()}; // Using the litteral
String[] arrOfStrings = {test.text, test.day, test.direction};
```

If you want to access/assign e.g. `text` from a data object storen in `arr`

```
arr[0].text = "Another String";
arrOfStrings[0].text = ...; // Not possible because it is storing strings not Data objects!
```

If you don't know the length before hand, you can not use an array (as they are of fixed length). Instead you could use `List`'s which are of variable length.

```
List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
test.add(1); // Add elements
test.size(); // How long is my array at the moment?
test.get(0); // Access first element (index 0) --> 1
```

Applying this to your code :

```
dados testObject = new dados(); // create a  "dados" object
List<dados> testList = new ArrayList<dados>();
testList.add(testObject);
testList.get(0); // Get object on index 0 (hence the first), hence "testObject"
```

To sort the `ArrayList` of `dados` objects you should implement a custom comparator to sort the objects like you want

```
public class OwnComparator implements Comparator<Dados> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Dados obj1, Dados obj2) {
        return obj1.text.compareTo(obj2.text); // Sort based on "text" field
    }
}
```

The actual sorting

```
Collections.sort(testList, new OwnComparator());
```

Comment: And if I do not know the number of elements?

Comment: Not in that way. Taking you example I can only create 10 right? But what if I dont know if I'll need 1 or 100?

Comment: @user3740471 Arrays are of fixed length, after creation their length can not be changed. However there exist `List`'s in Java which are of variable length ;) I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I needed

Comment: And that way I can I acess the element?

Comment: @user3740471 With the `get` method. `test.get(0);` will acces the first element (index 0).

Comment: List<dados> vetor = new ArrayList<dados>();
So having it like this I can create this way:  vetor.add(0); ?
And accessing it vetor.get(0);

Comment: @user3740471 `vetor.add(0);` will add the `Integer` 0 to the list, however in your code it is a list of `dados` objects and not `Integer`. I edited my code again.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions. But before I was sorting the array based on one field of the class. How can I do it now?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you reassigned the array to something else, this is your problem.

```
dados vetor[]={};
```

You create an empty array - there is no data object at vetor[0] for you to set the text of. If you know the number of elements you'll have when you declare the array, you can use the following to create an array to hold all of them.

```
dados[] vetor  = new dados[10];
```

To actually create an element in that array and set its text, you need to create a new object.

```
vetor[0] = new data();
vetor[0].text = "Some text";
```

Alternatively, create and set the values for the data object before adding it to the array:

```
data myData = new data();
myData.text = "Some text";
vetor[0] = myData;
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Just one more thing. What if I don't know the number of elements beforehand?

Comment: Not in that way. Taking you example I can only create 10 right? But what if I dont know if I'll need 1 or 100?

Comment: @user3740471 @hyperZ If you don't know the number of elements in the array before you create it, you can not use `length` - that only works when the array is full. The easiest way in Java would be to use one of the `Collection` classes - for example `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your class name is "dados" and not "data".
Your array does not have any elements, hence the error. 
Initialize your array to a certain number of elements and then assign the text property.

```
    dados[] vetor  = new dados[10];
    vetor[0] = new dados();
    vetor [0].text = "xx";

    dados[] vetor2 = {new dados(), new dados()};  // initialize to 2 elements
    vetor2[0].text = "xx";
```

Comment: Yes it is "dados".
I initialized it like this
final dados vetor[] = new dados[50];  but I still get the error. And how can I do if I do not know the number of elements I will need?

Comment: Also initialize your text string because it is null when object is instantiated